# How to bind the password field Prompt Text Property to the result of a method in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, bind

> I use the JFXPasswordField and the Label Float 'ON'. So I need to change the prompt while the user is entering the pass according to the input's strength.

I need to bind the property text of a pass field to its strength which is calculated in a function that returns a string as the strength.

> Here is the method :

```
private String getPassStrength() {
    int strength = foo(passwordField.getText());
    if (strength < 4) {
        return "Password is weak";
    } else {
        return "Password is good";
    }
}
```

And I used different types of bindings such as StringProperty and CreateStringBinding but none worked.

> For example :

```
passwordField.promptTextProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(this::getPassQuality));
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

> Edit:
>
> > The previous "password" reference was actually the "password field"
> > The Pass Field input variable was omitted, because I have the reference in the Controller.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are you trying to change the TextProperty upon text change?

Comment: I am going to change the prompt text upon text change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, I would do it like follows

```
password.promptTextProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() - > this.getPassStrength(), myPasswordField.textProperty()));
```

As you noticed I have the `password` variable which is (I hope) a Label, and a `myPasswordField` which is a JFXPasswordField.

The 'promptText' of a (password)textfield is only visible the field is empty. A better name for it would be 'placeholder', as it is meant for a content-information/hint. If you want a popup-message instead, you'l need to implement it yourself (using something like `PopupControl` or `Tooltip`).

Comment: I edited the code. I actually had the pass field's reference in the controller and because of that the method had no inputs so I used "this::getPassQuality". I forgot to delete it from the prototype.

Comment: The answer still stands from what I can figure out. If this is not enough to solve the problem, than please provide us with a clear explanation of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I use the JFXPasswordField and the Label Float 'ON'. So I need to change the prompt while the user is entering the pass according to the input's strength.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Actually the "myPasswordField.textProperty()" part was needed :)